# jQuery animation glitchy at the end

Tags: jquery, css

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CurSA/) (the result window should be made large).

When one of the accordion elements shrinks down to the end, there is a glitch. I've been spending hours on trying to solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing happens on that page for me.  I noticed you are using mootools as your js library and your question is marked jQuery, but even after changing it to use jQuery it still didn't work.

Comment: For others - looks like the .channel element is a good place to start

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a result of having outer margins set on the element(s) that disappears. jQuery will animate the height / width of the element until those values go down to 0, but the outer margins remain constant and the element immediately goes to display: none.

Try adding a containing element around the element you want to animate, and animate the containing element only.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work. I don't think it's a margin problem

Comment: Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ctde5/8/) for a simplified version of the problem.

Comment: It's the padding then. I tried removing padding from all of the elements and you don't have that "glitch" anymore. The problem is you are animating / hiding an internal element while that element still has 20px padding being applied to it from the parent container. When that element's width or height reaches 0, it then goes to "display: none", the parent container instantly drops the padding - goes from 20px to 0.

Comment: Sounds promising. Do you have a fiddle I could see?

Comment: I tested myself (but did not save) by taking the existing fiddle and setting ALL padding values to 0. Try that and start working from there. My original answer is the way to go about it. Ensure that the containing or animated elements do not have any external padding or margins applied.